Persistent Disk SSD (GB) quota related to ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED?
We have a Cloud Workflows orchestrating few Cloud Batch jobs, on of them running for hours.
After few weeks running, today, we started to have problems.
Creating the batch, we are getting ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED errors. First though was about machines availability in that zone, but moving to from us-central1 to europe-west3 did not fix the problem.
Then, doing investigating a little bit, we realised that we are at 96% Persistent Disk SSD (GB) for the zone us-central1, as the attached picture shows.
First question: May the current usage quote block the instantiation of new machines? If yes, why the error says that there is a problems with zone?
Second question: How to know what is consuming this quota. We are not aware of using this amount of SSD disks. Could be a Google Cloud Shell that one person is using daily to run few jobs manually?
Notes:

In Compute Engine, no Disks, Storage pools, etc.

Any advice will be welcome. Thanks!

After 6h and looks like the graph and quota value is not updated.


Your current disk usage might affect the VMs.
Because some resources are deployed at a zonal level and therefore they have the limits there.
You will need to check that specific screenshot you are mentioning or you can create alerts from Cloud Monitoring regarding resource usage.
And also it might end up being a limitation of Google itself of not having enough resources in that region.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability

Thanks @MrThompson The problem is that I'm not aware of using ssd persistent disk. And of course, not 500GB. As in my comment, in the Compute Engine section, there are not disk defined. So how to know what is consuming it?

If you go here https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/disksAdd do you see something? You ought to check the disk section to see what disks you have and to where they are attached.

No disks. Empty.

Looks like it was a problem in the GCP side.
I was able to create a virtual machine with a small disk of 30GB.
Just after that, all graphs are fine and moved from 480GB to 30GB as expected.
After deleting the VM, no usage and I was able to use it with no problems.
This looks not good to me and I'm concern about how often this will occurs.
